# jQuery post to asp.net page error : The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value

Tags: asp.net, post, jquery, query-string

I am trying to do a jQuery post the content of a text editor to an asp.net page (asp.net 4.0) from my javascript.The asp.net page will receive it and save it to db.I append the text editor's content in the querystring.When the content is big, I am getting the following exception

```
The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.
```

It works fine for small content.But when the content is big,It throws an error

Here is my javascript code

```
  var content1 = $("#txtAdminLabelEdit"+id).val();
  content = encodeURIComponent(content1);
  var url = "handlers/adminhandler.aspx?mode=savecontent&page=home&lid=1&vid=2&ltxt=" + content;

            $.post(url, function (data) {
                if (data == "yes") {
                 //do something
                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is this ASP.net 4.0? if then you can set the `maxQueryStringLength` like this.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestPathLength="360" maxQueryStringLength="1024" />
```